# Deserialize xml <Result xmlns=''> was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I having a bit of trouble find out what cause this problem and how to resolve it.

After google for others who had the same error, It still did work. So I hope someone can help or lead me in the right direction.

I'm trying to deserialize a xml from a web service to an object.

The xml:

```
<Result>
    <UserStatus Status="34" StatusFrom="140729143619" ClientType="4" 
                LogOnServer="NcoreConnect" SIPServer="10.16.3.10" Device="tel:201" 
                DeviceStatus="0" DeviceStatusFrom="140729134828" ServerTime="140731090408" 
                IsLoggedOn="True" IsAgent="True" CallCount="0" AnsweredCount="0" 
                Interactions="" Message="" SessionID="a123a38d-d00d-47c0-af03-2b63f40fb8a6" 
                DiversionStatus="0" DiversionDestination="" OldMessageCount="0" 
                NewMessageCount="0">BR</UserStatus>
</Result>
```

I then pasted the xml as classes

`UserStatus.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace project.ExternalWebServices
{
  /// <remarks/>
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
  //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
  [XmlRoot("Result")]
  public partial class Result
  {
    private ResultUserStatus userStatusField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ResultUserStatus UserStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return this.userStatusField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.userStatusField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ResultUserStatus
{
    private byte statusField;
    private ulong statusFromField;
    private byte clientTypeField;
    private string logOnServerField;
    private string sIPServerField;
    private string deviceField;
    private byte deviceStatusField;
    private ulong deviceStatusFromField;
    private ulong serverTimeField;
    private string isLoggedOnField;
    private string isAgentField;
    private byte callCountField;
    private byte answeredCountField;
    private string interactionsField;
    private string messageField;
    private string sessionIDField;
    private byte diversionStatusField;
    private string diversionDestinationField;
    private byte oldMessageCountField;
    private byte newMessageCountField;
    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte Status
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.statusField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public ulong StatusFrom
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusFromField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.statusFromField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte ClientType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.clientTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.clientTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string LogOnServer
    {
        get
        {
            return this.logOnServerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.logOnServerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string SIPServer
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sIPServerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sIPServerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Device
    {
        get
        {
            return this.deviceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.deviceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte DeviceStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return this.deviceStatusField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.deviceStatusField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public ulong DeviceStatusFrom
    {
        get
        {
            return this.deviceStatusFromField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.deviceStatusFromField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public ulong ServerTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this.serverTimeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.serverTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string IsLoggedOn
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isLoggedOnField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isLoggedOnField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string IsAgent
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isAgentField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isAgentField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte CallCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.callCountField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.callCountField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte AnsweredCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.answeredCountField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.answeredCountField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Interactions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.interactionsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.interactionsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return this.messageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.messageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string SessionID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sessionIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sessionIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte DiversionStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diversionStatusField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.diversionStatusField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string DiversionDestination
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diversionDestinationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.diversionDestinationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte OldMessageCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.oldMessageCountField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.oldMessageCountField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte NewMessageCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newMessageCountField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.newMessageCountField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}


}
```

The method that calls the web service:

```
public ResultUserStatus UserStatus(string userName)
    {
        string req = "req=userStatus";
        string user = "user=" + userName;
       //UserStatusResult result;
        using (WebClient proxy = new WebClient())
        {
            proxy.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " +   
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("br:br"));
            proxy.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/xml");

            try
            {
                var response = proxy.DownloadString(webServiceBasePath + req + "&" + user);


                var rootAttribute = new XmlRootAttribute();
                rootAttribute.IsNullable = true;

                var serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof (ResultUserStatus), rootAttribute);

                object res;

                using (TextReader read = new StringReader(response))
                {
                   res = serialize.Deserialize(read);
                }                   

                return (ResultUserStatus)res;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception breaks here on this line

```
res = serialize.Deserialize(read);
```

with the error:

> was not expected.
>
> [InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.]
>
> Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderResultUserStatus.Read3_ResultUserStatus() +262

Does anyone have ideas of what this could be?

Comment: [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
why comment off this line 

and added 
[XmlRoot("Result")] ?

Comment: I was trying to see if that was the problem. But I'm thinking it might have something to do with no Namespace in the xml or am I wrong?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487571/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part-2

Perhaps you can directly remove those line base on the sample provided in the link

Comment: Solved:

Deleted the class and made a new one, the same way, Paste XML as Classes.

I didn't find out why it didn't work, probably a syntax error. But it works now.